# How to create custom shortcut in Outlook for archiving email in a folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

Since Outlook does not have an official Archive folder like Gmail, I created an Archive folder. I would like to go through emails and send them to the archive folder using a keyboard shortcut. How can I set this up?

Edit: I should have clarified. I am asking for a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for the mac. Outlook does not offer inbuilt shortcuts, but you can use Mac's in-built shortcut ability to create a shortcut.
To setup a Gmail style Archive button/folder in Outlook on OSX, including a custom button to archive a message or thread, do the following:

1. Create a folder named "Archive"
2. Right click any message and select "Move->Choose Folder"
3. Pick the Archive folder.
4. Notice that the move menu now has an entry for the archive folder. In my case this was "Archive (xxx@yyy.com)"
5. Open System Preference, Keyboard and Select "App Shortcuts"
6. Create a new shortcut, using the exact name of the menu item. I chose command-alt-a. My menu item was name "Archive (xxx@yyy.com)"

Answer (score 1):

> > Since Outlook does not have an official Archive folder like Gmail

If you are using an Exchange account on Outlook, a Archive foldder will be created.

You can create a keyboard shortcut for this via the steps below:

1. In Quick Steps tab, click Create New.

[image]

2. Choose Move to folder > select your Archive folder.

[image]

3. Choose a shortcut key for this action.

[image]

4. Click Finish. Then you can select a message and press the shortcut key to move it to the Archive folder.